# storybook Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: storybook

I've got an issue with storybook using React. I've got a modal which is rendered inside a dom element (id=protal).

I will like to know how can I wrap or add a dom element in my storybook to make it work.

thanks for your time

Comment: Have you looked at using a decorator?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `.storybook/preview-body.html` file and add your container element in it.

For more details see the docs here https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/story-rendering